# How to use this function to return the option value

Tags: php, class

I can't seem to get it to return the option value I want.

The sql query which I want it to run is:

```
SELECT `profile_value` FROM `login_profiles` WHERE `pfield_id` = 1 AND `user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

I have tried this

```
<?php $profile->getOption('1', false, true, '1'); ?>
```

and the same without the quotes around the id's but it didn't work.

```
/**
 * Retrieves an option value based on option name.
 *
 * @param     string    $option    Name of option to retrieve.
 * @param     bool      $check     Whether the option is a checkbox.
 * @param     bool      $profile   Whether to return a profile field, or an admin setting.
 * @param     int       $id        Required if profile is true; the user_id of a user.
 * @return    string    The option value.
 */
public function getOption($option, $check = false, $profile = false, $id = '') {

    if (empty($option)) return false;

    $option = trim($option);

    if ( $profile ) {
        $params = array(
            ':option' => $option,
            ':id'     => $id
        );
        $sql = "SELECT `profile_value` FROM `login_profiles` WHERE `pfield_id` = :option AND `user_id` = :id LIMIT 1;";
    } else {
        $params = array( ':option' => $option );
        $sql = "SELECT `option_value` FROM `login_settings` WHERE `option_name` = :option LIMIT 1;";
    }

    $stmt = $this->query($sql, $params);

    if(!$stmt) return false;

    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $result = $result ? $result[0] : false;

    if($check)
        $result = !empty($result) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';

    return $result;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: `i cant seem to get it to return the option value i want.` ... what does that mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What are you expecting and what does it return? In other words, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I have tried <?php $profile->getOption('1', false, true, '1'); ?> as it says.

Comment: @cillosis nothing is returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided code is not supposed to do anything:

```
<?php $profile->getOption('1', false, true, '1'); ?>
```

It's hard to guess based on *i cant seem to get it to return the option value i want*, but I see you return a HTML attribute, so what you probably want to do is

```
<?php echo $profile->getOption('1', false, true, '1'); ?>
```